# Defining and returning a tree of objects from a Google Endpoints Python server

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Suppose I have some entity that supports a parent/child relationship. Something like:

```
class Employee(ndb.Model):
  name = ndb.StringProperty()
  boss = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Employee)
```

Such a structure would allow me to nest Boss/Employees arbitrarily deep.

Alternatively, I could use entity *keys* to define parents, omitting the boss property from the object altogether.

My questions are:

1. What are the pros and cons of using a KeyProperty versus a
   parent key.
2. How should I return the *whole tree* from an Python Google
   Endpoints server?

Answer (score 0):

A `KeyProperty` is mutable after entity creation. Parent keys are immutable after creation, which means you have to recreate the `Employee` record if the boss ever changes. Parent keys allow you to do ancestor queries, so you can say, get all employees directly or indirectly under a manager. However, if that manager gets a new manager, you have to recreate the entire subtree. You probably want the former, unless your data is pretty immutable, without many cross references with other entities.

If you are returning it as part of an API, I would say this is a sub-optimal and non-RESTful decision. Such an operation is expensive and not resource-based. Generally, resources link to other resources rather than embedding them. I'd say a less expensive operation is just to list all employees and let your client reconstruct the tree instead. The response could look something like this:

```
{
  'items': [
    {
      'id': '/employees/1'
      'name': 'Alice',
      'boss': /employees/2'
    },
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually, I mistakenly used StructuredProperty when I meant to use KeyProperty. I corrected this in my original post.

Comment: Also, in what way is getting a resource with hierarchical structure ("org chart" in this case) "non-RESTful"?

Comment: Hi @DougKnesek, I have adjusted my answer. Hope that helps.